# Getting a value from list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

How can I get a value from list and use it somewhere else (for example in "if" statement)?

```
<h2> <form>
<select id="day">
        <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option>
        <option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option>
        <option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option>              <option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option>
        <option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>

    </select>
    <select id="month">
        <option>Styczen</option><option>Luty</option><option>Marzec</option><option>Kwiecien</option><option>Maj</option>
        <option>Czerwiec</option><option>Lipiec</option><option>Sierpien</option><option>Wrzesien</option>
        <option>Pazdziernik</option><option>Listopad</option><option>Grudzien</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

I need to use selected value - and depending on choosed numbers I want to make some buttons inactive.

Comment: Why not google it or use search function on SO???

Comment: I'd suggest you share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Type this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
days=$("#day option")
months=$("#month option")

//Now you have a JQuery object which acts like an array. 
//Just get the html of each value with `.html()`.

days[0].html() //this is 1 
months[3].html() //this is Kwiecien
</script>
```